# Necesito hacer que el propietario no pueda tener 2 veces la misma casa

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo programando, ya he hecho preguntas antes sobre este proyecto que hago, es sencillo supongo y he avanzado con él y siempre me dejan cosas extras que hacerle pero aún así hay muchas cosas que no conozco, ahora d**ebo hacer que el objeto que creé de la clase propietario no pueda recibir 2 veces la misma casa**, se la asigno por el Id, aunque sé que quizá no lo hice de la mejor manera, pero me funciona y es lo último que debo saber para completarlo, debo presentarlo mañana en la mañana, espero que me pueda ayudar porque tengo mucho pensando y aún no se me ocurre la manera de hacerlo, no sé si hay alguna función que no conozco o deba mejorar algunas cosas.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pregunta;
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor ingrese el nombre del primer propietario : ");
        Propietario persona1 = new Propietario { Nombre = Console.ReadLine() };

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el apellido de el primer propietario:");
        persona1.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la dirección de la primera casa: ");
        Casa casa1 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la primera casa: ");
        casa1.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (casa1.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
            casa1.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la direccion de la segunda casa: ");
        Casa casa2 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la segunda casa: ");
        casa2.MetrosCuadrados = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (casa2.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
            casa2.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la direccion de la tercera casa: ");
        Casa casa3 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la tercera casa: ");
        casa3.MetrosCuadrados = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (casa3.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
            casa3.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el id de la casa que le quiere asignar al primer propietario: ");
        int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (id == 1)
        {
            persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
            persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
        }
        else if(id == 3)
        {
            persona1.AddCasa(casa3);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Desea asignar otra casa a este propietario?");
        pregunta = Console.ReadLine();

        while (pregunta == "si")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el id de la casa que desea agregar a este propietario: ");
            id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(id == 1)
            {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
            }
            else if(id == 2)
            {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
            }
            else if(id == 3)
            {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa3);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Desea agregar otra casa?");
            pregunta = Console.ReadLine();

        }         

        Console.WriteLine($"Nombre completo: {persona1.Nombre} {persona1.Apellido} \n");

        foreach (Casa c in persona1.Listacasas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Informacion de la casa: \n Id: {c.IdCasa} \n Direccion: {c.Direccion}\n Metros cuadrados: {c.MetrosCuadrados} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"La cantidad de casas de este propietario es de: {persona1.CantidadCasas(persona1)}\n La casa más grande es de:  {persona1.CasaMasGrande()}m^2\n La más pequeñas es de: {persona1.CasaMasPequeña()} ");


    }
}
public class Casa
{
    public  int IdCasa { get; private set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int MetrosCuadrados { get; set; } 

    private static int internalId;
    public Casa(string direccion, int metrosC)
    {
        this.Direccion = direccion;
        this.MetrosCuadrados = metrosC;
        Casa.internalId++;
        this.IdCasa = internalId;
    }
}

public class Propietario
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    public List<Casa> Listacasas { get => listacasas; set => listacasas = value; }

    List<Casa> listacasas = new List<Casa>();
    public void AddCasa(Casa casa)
    {
        this.Listacasas.Add(casa);
    }

    public int CantidadCasas(Propietario persona)
    {
        return Listacasas.Count();
    }

    public int CasaMasGrande()
    {
        var casaMax = this.listacasas.Max(Object => Object.MetrosCuadrados);
        return casaMax;
    }

    public int CasaMasPequeña()
    {
        var casaMin = this.listacasas.Min(Object => Object.MetrosCuadrados);
        return casaMin;
    }
}
```

Comment: No se si te entiendo muy bien. No te sirve, en el método `AddCasa`, comprobar si `Listacasas` contiene alguna casa con el id de la que quieres añadir?

Answer (score 2):

El problema que veo es que estas usando variables en lugar de listas o array para conservar las casas, si en lugar de tener `casa1`, `casa2`, `casaN`, tendrias

```
List<Casa> casas = new List<Casa>();
```

podrias usar el `casas.Add()` para ubicar cada instancia y luego recuperarla por el id

Tambien podria ser

```
Casa[] casas = new Casas[3];
```

eso es un array, pero debes saber que solo seran 3 casa, a List te permite definir de forma dinamica

Asi te evitas tener que poner 3 veces el mismo codigo para las casas

```
List<Casa> casas = new List<Casa>();

for(int i=1; i <=3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la dirección de la casa {0}: ", i);
    string direccion = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la casa {0}: ", i);
    int metros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    while (metros <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
        metros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Casa casa = new Casa(id: i, direccion: direccion, metrosC: metros);
    casas.Add(casa);
}
```

Agregale un parametro de `id` a la `Casa` asi puedes asignarlo desde codigo cuando se instancia

Para buscar usarias

```
Console.WriteLine("ingrese el id de la casa que le quiere asignar al primer propietario: ");
int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Casa casa = casas.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.id = id);

persona1.AddCasa(casa);
```

Bueno alli use `linq` con el `FirstOrDefault()` para localizar por Id, pero podrias iterar si quieres

```
Console.WriteLine("ingrese el id de la casa que le quiere asignar al primer propietario: ");
int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Casa casa = null;
foreach(var item in casas)
{
    if(item.id == id)
    {
        casa = item;
        break;
    }
}

persona1.AddCasa(casa);
```

eso es lo mismo que hace `linq` pero mas simple en una linea.

**Validar repetidos**

Para evitar sis existe al usar listas podras validarlo previa agregar el item en la colecion, algo como ser:

```
Casa casa = null;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ingrese el id de la casa que le quiere asignar al primer propietario: ");
    int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    foreach(var item in casas)
    {
        if(item.id == id)
        {
            casa = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(persona1.Listacasas.Any(x=>x.id == casa.id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La casa que intente agregar ya existe");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

persona1.AddCasa(casa);
```

en este caso me ayudo del `Any()` de `linq` para realizar una validacion rapida, pero podrias como en el caso anterior iterar la lista `Listacasas` he ir preguntando si el id existe.

Parto de la premisa que `Listacasas` es una lista o cleccion que ya esta instanciada, por eso accedo a esta para ver si hay una casa con el mismo id

Use un `while` para que quede en un ciclo de validacion, por supuesto no inclui todas, como ser, si se quiere salir del ciclo sin agregar una casa al propietario, pero creo que sirve de base

Comment: Yo sacaria toda referencia a linq. Si el usuario esta aprendiendo, linq es sugar para lo que necesita. Primero tiene que aprender a iterar y buscar.

Comment: es que linq resulta tan practico y queda tan bien en el codigo que lo tengo super incorporado y trato que los demas tambien les guste, pero veras que en el codigo puse ambas alternativas, siempre se puede iterar la lista para ver si hay una concidencia

Answer (score 1):

> Bueno puedes hacer una condición rápida utilizando una lista de enteros como el siguiente ejemplo **NOTA no es una solución optima pero puede funcionar.**

List list = new List();
list.add(1);

> Ahi vas agregando cada id de la casa y luego buscar si existe o no existe en la lista;

boolean existe = list.contains(idDelaCasa);

> A continuación esta condición de acuerdo a tu ejemplo

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> listCasa = new List<int>();
            string pregunta;
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor ingrese el nombre del primer propietario : ");
            Propietario persona1 = new Propietario { Nombre = Console.ReadLine() };

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el apellido de el primer propietario:");
            persona1.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la dirección de la primera casa: ");
            Casa casa1 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la primera casa: ");
            casa1.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (casa1.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
                casa1.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la direccion de la segunda casa: ");
            Casa casa2 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la segunda casa: ");
            casa2.MetrosCuadrados = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (casa2.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
                casa2.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la direccion de la tercera casa: ");
            Casa casa3 = new Casa(direccion: Console.ReadLine(), metrosC: 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los metros cuadrados de la tercera casa: ");
            casa3.MetrosCuadrados = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (casa3.MetrosCuadrados <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Los metros deben ser mayor a 0");
                casa3.MetrosCuadrados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }


            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el id de la casa que le quiere asignar al primer propietario: ");
            int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            boolean existe = list.contains(id);
           if(existe){
              if (id == 1)
              {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
                listCasa.add(id); 
              }
              else if (id == 2)
              {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
                listCasa.add(id); 
              }
              else if(id == 3)
              {
                persona1.AddCasa(casa3);
                listCasa.add(id); 
              }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Desea asignar otra casa a este propietario?");
            pregunta = Console.ReadLine();

            while (pregunta == "si")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el id de la casa que desea agregar a este propietario: ");
                id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                boolean existe = list.contains(id);
                if(existe){
                    if(id == 1)
                    {
                        persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
                        listCasa.add(id); 
                    }
                    else if(id == 2)
                    {
                        persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
                        listCasa.add(id); 
                    }
                    else if(id == 3)
                    {
                        persona1.AddCasa(casa3);
                        listCasa.add(id);   
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Desea agregar otra casa?");
                pregunta = Console.ReadLine();

            }         

            Console.WriteLine($"Nombre completo: {persona1.Nombre} {persona1.Apellido} \n");

            foreach (Casa c in persona1.Listacasas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Informacion de la casa: \n Id: {c.IdCasa} \n Direccion: {c.Direccion}\n Metros cuadrados: {c.MetrosCuadrados} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"La cantidad de casas de este propietario es de: {persona1.CantidadCasas(persona1)}\n La casa más grande es de:  {persona1.CasaMasGrande()}m^2\n La más pequeñas es de: {persona1.CasaMasPequeña()} ");


        }
    }
```